# Save nested objects in database with one method using Peewee or other ORM

Tags: python, mysql, orm, peewee

Lets say i have this models:

```
class user(Model):
   rep = ForeignKeyField('reputation')

class reputation(Model):
   metrics = ForeignKeyField('metric')

class metric(Model):
   rate = IntegerField()
   stars = IntegerField()
   comments = IntegerField()
```

Using playhouse module shortcuts i can convert a entire dict to a user object *dict_to_model*. This main object contain nested objects already fullfiled with all info i need. I am looking a ORM method to simplify the way i am saving this user to database. ex: user.create_all_recursive(). I already did a search and i didnt find anything in the peewee documentation

This is just a sample but currently i have 1 model with 23 nested objects that i receive from a unique API. I was looking for some method or trick to create all rows inside database in sequence starting from the nested ones. In my sample if i try to save user.create() using peewee i will get a error informing that correspond metric is not there to connect.

Answer (score 0):

Check out `ModelClass._meta.model_graph`, which traverses the graph of model refs and backrefs. If you're going from the "root" model to all the dependencies, you want to search back-references, so something like this:

```
from peewee import *

class A(Model): pass
class B(Model):
    a = ForeignKeyField(A)
class C(Model):
    b = ForeignKeyField(B)
    c = ForeignKeyField('self', null=True)
class D(Model):
    b = ForeignKeyField(B)

A._meta.model_graph(refs=False)                                                        
# returns:
[(None, <Model: A>, None),
 (<ForeignKeyField: B.a>, <Model: B>, True),
 (<ForeignKeyField: C.b>, <Model: C>, True),
 (<ForeignKeyField: D.b>, <Model: D>, True),
 (<ForeignKeyField: C.c>, <Model: C>, True)]
```

You would probably want to iterate in reverse order.